# CSS property value from a variable

Tags: html, css, angular

I am working on an angular project and operating with a table with collapsabe rows.
Something like that: https://stackblitz.com/angular/oyybnyopyemm?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.css

I face the issue that although I set the height of my row to 0, it is refuse to be invisible.

I noticed that when I set the property "visibility: collapse", it works like I want it to.
Although I want to hide only the rows which are empty, so not all of them.

Is there a way to set the value of visibility property from a variable:

```
<tr id="para" mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']"
                style="height: 0px;"
                [hidden]="expandedElement === undefined || expandedElement === null"></tr>
```

Something like that:

```
<tr id="para" mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']"
                style="height: 0px; visibility=getVaueFromMyOwnMethod()"
                [hidden]="expandedElement === undefined || expandedElement === null">
```

Thanks a lot!

---

EDIT:

I managed to do that this was:

[ngStyle]="{'visibility': calcRowisibility(row)}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ngClass.

1. Create a class which can set visibility: collapse.

   ```
    .hidden-row {
      visibility: collapse;
    }
   ```
2. Add ngClass to the  to decide if a row is hidden or not. For example if you want to hide a row when name=='Helium' just add below to

   ***[ngClass]="{'hidden-row':element.name=='Helium'}"***

like this:

```
<tr id="para" mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']"
                
                [ngClass]="{'hidden-row':element.name=='Helium'}""></tr>
```

3. You can add a function to your ts code and use this function to check if a row is visible or hidden. Using a ts function your code will be cleaner if you should change complicated condition. For example

   ```
    calcRowisibility(name){

    return ( name=='Helium' && name.length>4 && name.startWith("h")) }
   ```

and:

```
[ngClass]="{'hidden-row': calcRowisibility(element.name) }"
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I managed to do that a similar way: [ngStyle]="{'visibility': calcRowisibility(row) }" Thank you for your help!